# How to compare two csv files by 2 columns?

Tags: c#, list, compare

I have 2 **csv** files

**1.csv**

```
spain;russia;japan
italy;russia;france
```

**2.csv**

```
spain;russia;japan
india;iran;pakistan
```

I read both files and add data to lists

```
var lst1= File.ReadAllLines("1.csv").ToList();
var lst2= File.ReadAllLines("2.csv").ToList();
```

Then I find all unique strings from both lists and add it to result lists

```
var rezList = lst1.Except(lst2).Union(lst2.Except(lst1)).ToList();
```

rezlist contains this data

```
[0] = "italy;russia;france"
[1] = "india;iran;pakistan"
```

At now I want to compare, make except and union by **second** and **third** column in all rows.

**1.csv**

spain;**russia**;japan

italy;**russia**;france

**2.csv**

spain;**russia**;japan

india;**iran**;pakistan

I think I need to split all rows by symbol ';' and make all **3** operations (**except**, **distinct** and **union**) but cannot understand how.

`rezlist` must contains

```
india;iran;pakistan
```

I added class

```
 class StringLengthEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
        {

            public bool Equals(string x, string y)
            {
               ...
            }

            public int GetHashCode(string obj)
            {
               ...
            }
        }



 StringLengthEqualityComparer stringLengthComparer = new StringLengthEqualityComparer();
 var rezList = lst1.Except(lst2,stringLengthComparer ).Union(lst2.Except(lst1,stringLengthComparer),stringLengthComparer).ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: moment. i add some code

Comment: Can you give an example what this program is supposed to do?

Comment: i add it to code. program must return     india;iran;pakistan

Comment: Can you please extend little bit more example of output. Also please provide some rules of how you want to create result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lst1 = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test\1.csv").Select(x => new StringWrapper(x)).ToList();
            var lst2 = File.ReadLines(@"D:\test\2.csv").Select(x => new StringWrapper(x));
            var set = new HashSet<StringWrapper>(lst1);
            set.SymmetricExceptWith(lst2);

            foreach (var x in set)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
            }

        }
    }

    struct StringWrapper : IEquatable<StringWrapper>
    {
        public string Value { get; }
        private readonly string _comparand0;
        private readonly string _comparand14;

        public StringWrapper(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
            var split = value.Split(';');
            _comparand0 = split[0];
            _comparand14 = split[14];
        }

        public bool Equals(StringWrapper other)
        {
            return string.Equals(_comparand0, other._comparand0, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                   && string.Equals(_comparand14, other._comparand14, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            return obj is StringWrapper && Equals((StringWrapper) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return ((_comparand0 != null ? StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(_comparand0) : 0)*397)
                       ^ (_comparand14 != null ? StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.GetHashCode(_comparand14) : 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is this the answer? And no explanation. Come on guys!

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear: for instance, is `india;iran;pakistan` the desired result primarily because **russia** is at element[1]?  Isn't it also included because element [2] **pakistan** does not match **france** and **japan**?  Even though thats unclear, I assume the desired result comes from either situation.

Then there is this: **`find all unique string from both lists`** which changes the nature dramatically.  So, I take it that the desired results are because "iran" appears in column[1] no where else in column[1] in either file and even if it did, that row would still be unique due to "pakistan" in col[2].

Also note that a data sample of 2 leaves room for a fair amount of error.

Trying to do it in one step makes it very confusing.  Since eliminating dupes found in 1.CSV is pretty easy, do it first:

```
// parse "1.CSV"
List<string[]> lst1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\1.csv").
            Select(line => line.Split(';')).
            ToList();

// parse "2.CSV"
List<string[]> lst2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\2.csv").
            Select(line => line.Split(';')).
            ToList();

// extracting once speeds things up in the next step
//  and leaves open the possibility of iterating in a method
List<List<string>> tgts = new List<List<string>>();
tgts.Add(lst1.Select(z => z[1]).Distinct().ToList());
tgts.Add(lst1.Select(z => z[2]).Distinct().ToList());

var tmpLst = lst2.Where(x => !tgts[0].Contains(x[1]) ||
                !tgts[1].Contains(x[2])).
                ToList();
```

That results in the items which are not in 1.CSV (no matching text in Col[1] nor  Col[2]).  If that is really all you need, you are done.

Getting unique rows within 2.CSV is trickier because you have to actually count the number of times each Col[1] item occurs to see if it is unique; then repeat for Col[2].  This uses GroupBy:

```
var unique = tmpLst.
    GroupBy(g => g[1], (key, values) =>
            new GroupItem(key, 
                    values.ToArray()[0], 
                    values.Count())
            ).Where(q => q.Count == 1).
    GroupBy(g => g.Data[2], (key, values) => new
            {
                Item = string.Join(";", values.ToArray()[0]),
                Count = values.Count()
            }
            ).Where(q => q.Count == 1).Select(s => s.Item).
        ToList();
```

The `GroupItem` class is trivial:

```
class GroupItem
{
    public string Item { set; get; }      // debug aide
    public string[] Data { set; get; }
    public int Count { set; get; }
            
    public GroupItem(string n, string[] d, int c)
    {
        Item = n;
        Data =  d;
        Count = c;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(";", Data);
    }
}
```

It starts with `tmpList`, gets the rows with a unique element at [1].  It uses a class for storage since at this point we need the array data for further review.

The second `GroupBy` acts on those results, this time looking at col[2]. Finally, it selects the joined string data.

#### Results

Using 50,000 random items in File1 (1.3 MB), 15,000 in File2 (390 kb). There were no naturally occurring unique items, so I manually made 8 unique in 2.CSV and copied 2 of them into 1.CSV.  The copies in 1.CSV should eliminate 2 if the 8 unique rows in 2.CSV making the expected result 6 unique rows:

[image]

`NepalX` and `ItalyX` were the repeats in both files and they correctly eliminated each other.

With each step it is scanning and working with less and less data, which seems to make it pretty fast for 65,000 rows / 130,000 data elements.

Comment: thx for response. all good work but speed is very very slow. I have 300k data in both csv-files. How increase speed ?

Comment: Yeah, thats the problem with small test data sets.  Updated the answer.  Drilling into the arrays is slow and testing duplicate elements is also.  As it says, it does files larger than yours in ~150ms now.

Answer (score 0):

your `GetHashCode()`-Method in EqualityComparer are buggy. Fixed version:

```
public int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
  return obj.Split(';')[1].GetHashCode();
}
```

now the result are correct:

```
// one result: "india;iran;pakistan"
```

btw. `"StringLengthEqualityComparer"`is not a good name ;-)

Comment: thx, another question. How compare strings by second and third column?

Comment: `[1]` already compares the second column, for first column use `[0]` for third column `[2]`. Change the bracket-values in your `Equals()` AND `GetHashCode()` methods.

Comment: how make it? can you share exampleS?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GetUnion(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2)
{
    List<string> lstUnion = new List<string>();
    foreach (string value in lst1)
    {
        string valueColumn1 = value.Split(';')[0];
        string valueColumn2 = value.Split(';')[1];
        string valueColumn3 = value.Split(';')[2];

        string result = lst2.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(";" + valueColumn2 + ";" + valueColumn3));

        if (result != null)
        {
            if (!lstUnion.Contains(result))
            {
                lstUnion.Add(result);
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```